# Decidability/recognizability of languages with strings lacking alphabet characters

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Suppose that $\Sigma = \{c_1, \dots, c_m\}$ is some finite alphabet and supposing $s \in \Sigma^*$, let $\mathcal{I}_j(s)$ denote the number of instances of character $c_j$ in $s$. Call a string $s$ *odd-parity absent* iff $|\{j : \mathcal{I}_j(s) = 0\}|$ is odd. That is, $s$ is odd-parity absent iff an odd number of characters from the alphabet are missing from $s$. Call a language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ odd-parity absent iff every string in $L$ is odd-parity absent.

I want to show whether or not the following proposition is true: if $L$ is odd-parity absent, then $L$ must be Turing decidable/recognizable.

At first, I was considering employing Rice's Theorem to show that the odd-parity absent language of Turing machine encodings is a non-trivial property and hence undecidable, but it seems conceivable that two equivalent Turing machine descriptions may be such that one is odd-parity absent and the other is not, and so this wouldn't be a valid property. Further, it seems we can always describe two equivalent Turing machines using two completely disjoint alphabets.

Also, I am not sure whether the proposition holds in the case of Turing recognizability.

Comment: How many languages are odd-parity absent? ​ ​

Comment: Infinitely many, because there are infinitely many odd-parity absent strings.

Comment: What kind of infinity? ​ ​

Comment: I was thinking that every single language could be odd-parity absent, since you could just add some extra characters to $\Sigma$ that don't actually appear in the target language, but I'm not sure.

Comment: How many subsets does an infinite set have? ​ ​

Comment: There are infinitely many, and each of these subsets/sublanguages must also be odd-parity absent.

Comment: What [kind of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)? ​ ​

Comment: "I was thinking that every single language could be odd-parity absent, since you could just add some extra characters to Σ that don't actually appear in the target language". But we have to consider only language L with L⊆Σ*, don't we?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.